# Creating a for loop to find the max value in a column vector

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, matrix

Hi I am writing a program in which the user inputs dimensions for a matrix, recieves a random matrix with the specified dimesions, and through  use of a for loop is returned the maximum values of each row and column.

Here is the code I have for the function I used to find the max of each row

```
function outmax = mymaxq (q)
outmax = q (1);
for i = 2:length (q)
    if q(i) > outmax
        outmax = q(i);
    end
end
end
```

The code for the function to find the max of each column:

```
function outmax2 = mymaxcol(z)
outmax2 = z(1);
for i = 2: length (y)
    if z(i) > outmax2
        outmax2 = z(i);
    end
end
end
```

The code for the overall script:

```
rows = input('Enter the number of rows: ');
columns = input ('Enter the number of columns: ');
mat = round(rand(rows , columns)*(30-1)+1)
[r,c] =size (mat);
for x = 1:r
    q = mat(x,:);
    outmax = mymaxq(q);
    fprintf ('The max of row %d is %d.\n',x,outmax)
end
for y = 1:c
    z = mat(:,y);
    outmax2 = mymaxcol(z);
    fprintf ('The max of column %d is %d.\n',y,outmax2)
end
```

However the column function is not working properly. My guess is because the length of the column vector is 1. What do I do to make it so the function works properly. Suggestions for using things other than length?

Comment: please search for questions on "matlab how to find maximum"!!...

Comment: Do you realize you can do it with `max`?

Comment: And that both your functions are the same?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this in such a long way as a homework assignment? What exactly is wrong with your code, it look to me like it should work. Although as Luis pointed out, your `mymaxcol` function is redundant, it's exactly the same as the other one so you're better off only using 1 of them.

Comment: You have a typo in the second function, third line: `y` should be `z`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `max(mat,[],1)` (gives maximum of each column) and `max(mat,[],2)` (gives maximum of each row)?

In any case, in the third line of your second function, `y` should be `z`. Or better, use only the first function. The second does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I am trying to do this withoutusing the max function. Th reason I put in the second function was to test a way to find the max of the columns. I've only been able to get max of rows.

Comment: I have tried the following code using the same function:              clear all
rows = input('Enter the number of rows: ');
columns = input ('Enter the number of columns: ');
mat = round(rand(rows , columns)*(30-1)+1)
[r,c] =size (mat);
for x = 1:r
  q = mat(x,:);
  outmax = mymaxq(q);
  fprintf ('The max of row %d is %d.\n',x,outmax)
  for y = 1:c
      q = mat(:,y);
      outmax = mymax(q);
      fprintf ('The max of column %d it %d.' ,y,outmax)
  end
end